# Get HTTP request time in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the duration of each HTTP request I send through Angular.js, to so I can send it to New Relic analytics. I can use transformRequest to find when any HTTP request is fired, and I can use responseInterceptors to get the completed request. But I can't find any way to link that information together.

Any suggestions to get the duration of HTTP requests? Ideally something that works with Angularjs Rails Resource: https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource?

Answer (score 1):

I got this code from one of the blogs for rendering overlays by default when an http request is made. I modified it a little bit to address your issue. See if this helps.

```
angular
    .module('analytics', [])
    .config(function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(function() {
            return function(promise) {
                // START YOUR TIMER
                var callReturn = function(r) { 
                  // END YOUR TIMER
                  total_time = START TIMER - END TIMER
                };

                return promise.then(callReturn, callReturn);
            };
        });
    });
```

Comment: Ah, I've been dancing around this for hours. It works if you add `return r;` to `callReturn`.

Comment: Actually, I can't get this solution to work, because I don't know how to start a timer specific to the HTTP request. This means that with multiple concurrent requests, it confuses the start or end times of different requests.

Comment: @DaanPoron... Afraid not. Ended up not being super high priority, but I'm still curious.

Comment: how about: var start = new Date().getTime(); var end = new Date().getTime(); total_time = end - start; ?